# create a dictionary for a certain range in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a following dictionary:

```
d1 = {}
```

I need to assign it the following values, but only the first `n` values from the following list:

```
all_examples=   ['A,1,1', 'B,2,1', 'C,4,4', 'D,4,5']
```

Final output: `d1={"A":[1,1],"B":[2,1]}`

---

#### 1st version of the Question:

> I have a following dictionary:
>
> ```
> d1 = {'UID': 'A12B4', 'name': 'John', 'email': 'hi@example.com'}
> ```
>
> How do I create a dictionary d2 such that d2 has the first n number of keys and values from d1?

#### 2nd version of the Question

> I have a following dictionary:
>       d1 = {}
>
> I need to assign it the following values, but only the first n values from the following list:
>
> ```
> all_examples=   ['A,1,1', 'B,2,1', 'C,4,4', 'D,4,5']
> ```

Comment: You can't since dict is an unordered collection.

Comment: @AvinashRaj made some changes to my question

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: err @ThaimanThatte you're sweet, but you just changed radically the meaning of your question.

Comment: I know it's borderline to do such an edit and I hope I won't get blamed for that, but I figured it can be useful to not have to look at the edit history to understand what the answers are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *How do I create a dictionary d2 such that d2 has the first n number of keys and values from d1?*

I'm sorry to tell you, but you shouldn't do that. At least, not with the stock `dict`. The reason is that no order is guaranteed in a `dict`, and whenever you'll add or remove a value, the order of the dict *CAN* change.

But if you really insist you could do:

```
>>> d1 = {1:'a', 3:'b', 2:'c', 4:'d'}
>>> d1
{1: 'a', 2: 'c', 3: 'b', 4: 'd'}
>>> d.keys()[:2]
[1, 2]
>>> {k : d[k] for k in d.keys()[:2]}
{1: 'a', 2: 'c'}
```

but my suggestion to you is to use an `OrderedDict` object, that will guarantee the order of the elements within the dict:

```
>>> od = OrderedDict()
>>> od[1] = 'a'
>>> od[3] = 'b'
>>> od[2] = 'c'
>>> od[4] = 'd'
>>> od
OrderedDict([(1, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (4, 'd')])
>>> od.keys()[:2]
[1, 3]
>>> OrderedDict([(k, od[k]) for k in od.keys()[:2]])
OrderedDict([(1, 'a'), (3, 'b')])
```

---

Ok, looks like you just changed *radically* your question, so here's the new answer:

```
>>> all_examples=   ['A,1,1', 'B,2,1', 'C,4,4', 'D,4,5']
>>> n = 2
>>> all_examples[:n]
['A,1,1', 'B,2,1']
```

here's how you select up to `n` values of a list.

---

once again, you're changing your question…

```
Final output: d1={"A":[1,1],"B":[2,1]}
```

well you can just do:

```
>>> {elt[0] : (elt[1], elt[2]) for elt in [elt.split(',') for elt in all_examples[:n]]}
{'A': ('1', '1'), 'B': ('2', '1')}
```

HTH

Comment: appreciated @zmo. sorry, i thought of using a rather easier way to create the dictionary